# Connecting PHP to Cloud SQL

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, mysqli, google-cloud-sql

I'm able to connect to my Cloud SQL through Desktop MySQL software, but now I'm trying to connect to the Database via PHP.

I have a PHP subdomain which does the server requests to MySQL, the PHP is live on a web accessible website whilst I work on an AngularJS project locally via `localhost:9000`

```
define("DB_HOST", "[my ip]:3306");
define("DB_NAME", "db");
define("DB_USER", "user");
define("DB_PASS", "pass");

$db = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

if (!$db) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
} else {
    echo 'Connected';
}
```

So if I check my PHP page I see that page displays `Connected` but my MySQLi queries are failing.

I have a simple GET which returns empty

```
$q = $db->query("SELECT * FROM items");

        $items = array();
        while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($q)) {
            $item = array(
                'id' => $r['id'],
                'item_id' => $r['item_id'],
                'name' => $r['name'],
                'json' => $r['json']
            );
            array_push($items, $item);
        }
```

Comment: What happens when you `SELECT "hello world";`?

Comment: @Mike if i replace `"SELECT * FROM items"` with `SELECT "hello world"` I get Error 500

Comment: Hmm weird.. What about `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM items`? Maybe there's actually nothing there.

Comment: @Mike `$q = mysql_query(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM items); echo $q` returns blank

Comment: this doesn't help you `mysql_error()` that doesn't mix with `mysqli_` - use `mysqli_error($db)`

Comment: plus you can't use `mysql_query` again, mixing APIs, can't do that.

Comment: @Mike any special reason why you asked the OP to use `SELECT "hello world";` ?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Just to see if it actually connected and could execute queries

Comment: @Donald did you change `mysql_error()` to `mysqli_error($db)`?

Comment: Also do `if(!$q){trigger_error("there was an error....".$db->error, E_USER_WARNING);}`

Comment: the PHP page has started to severlyy lag. I may jsut give up

Answer (score -1):

Usually you need to set your PHP with the first line with this:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: This hasn't changed anything

Comment: Weird.  I am keeping eye on this and find out your solution that you would get to make script to work.